# Able to connect the visual studio 2010 to Remote SharePoint 2010 server?

Tags: sharepoint-server, visual-studio

In my organization they ask to doing the task.

I explained to the people that we can’t connect to remote SharePoint url  and work, we need SharePoint 2010 server to be installed in the local machine.

I researched the result value is null,

They asking to try in another method like

- SharePoint Redistributable,
- SharePoint SDK.

Are there any possible ways to connect the remote SharePoint 2010 server with the local system?

Answer (score 1):

The method that works best if you have a powerful enough pc (quad core with 16 gig of ram) is to use hyper-v to set up a VM running SharePoint and Visual Studio. You can follow these [TechNet instructions - SharePoint 2010 Setup a Development Environment](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/8871.sharepoint-2010-setup-a-development-environment.aspx). 
Failing that and without going down the path of sandbox solutions you have very little choice other than running Visual Studio on the same machine as SharePoint though I must reiterate that this should **NOT** be done on a production machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Visual Studio 2010, it's not possible. But if you use Visual Studio 2012 or 2013 you can publish **Sandboxed Solutions** to a SharePoint Farm. I don't really know if it works on SharePoint 2010, but it's worth a try.

Your second option would be to use SharePoint Designer 2010, but that limits you to client side technologies.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft have deprecated support for Sandbox code solutions.  You only have 1 choice for farm development and that is to install VS on a SharePoint server.  [Link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2014/01/14/deprecation-of-custom-code-in-sandboxed-solutions.aspx)

I would not recommend installing it on a production server.  If you need to do development on SharePoint then you would be better looking at Virtualization.